# File linkage in PHP

Tags: php

I need some help in linking a file in php.

Here is what I am looking for:

I have two files `process.php` and `index.php`, both placed in different directories.

This is the full path to `process.php` file:

```
/home/happy92a/public_html/ggytg45ffs43456/wp/wp-content/themes/Funizm/loginsystem/process.php
```

I want to require_once `index.php` within the `process.php` file, How can I require it, here is the full path of index.php:

```
/home/happy92a/public_html/ggytg45ffs43456/wp/wp-content/plugins/plugged/index.php
```

I have already tried:

`dirname(__FILE__)` but it gives the path to the current file (`process.php`) not the (`index.php`) which I want to include within process.php file.

I have also tried it with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but still it does not work also I have read it is bad practice to use server variable.

Comment: "`dirname(__FILE__)` but it gives the path to the current file (process.php)" <-- this is exactly what you want. Make it relative to the current path: `__DIR__ . '/../../../plugins/plugged/index.php'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am assuming your DOCUMENT_ROOT is at `/home/happy92a/public_html/` if so using that as a base to build an absolute path by doing the following.

```
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/ggytg45ffs43456/wp/wp-content/plugins/plugged/index.php");
```

I read that you do not wish to use DOCUMENT_ROOT. you can then establish a constant for your wordpress installation called WP_DIR

```
define('WP_DIR', '/home/happy92a/public_html/ggytg45ffs43456/wp/');
require_once (WP_DIR . "wp-content/plugins/plugged/index.php");
```

Comment: Thanks! it works but can we make it more dynamic somehow so for instance the link is picked up even if server is changed

Comment: you can place the constant file in the root of wp install and assign the value `__DIR__`

Answer (score 0):

Use DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/ggytg45ffs43456/wp/wp-content/plugins/plugged/index.php');
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
require_once('./ggytg45ffs43456/wp/wp-content/plugins/plugged/index.php');
```

Comment: Could the person down-voting please elaborate?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but what you just suggested uses the current directory, same as omitting the dot altogether in this scenario.